# MySQL regexp: repetition-operator operand invalid, can't get ordinals

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to select all ordinals (things like 1st, 22nd, 8th, etc) from a column, and my query looks like:

```
SELECT `Date` from meetings2 where `Date` REGEXP '(?<=[0-9])(?:st|nd|rd|th)'
```

but when I run it, MySQL throws the following error:

```
Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp
```

(I have also tried with * instead of ? because I read MySQL does not support ?, but I get the same error)

Comment: With `REGEXP` you can only get all the records where the regex pattern finds  a match. And your pattern contains a lookbehind that MySQL REGEXP does not support (it does not support non-capturing groups either). It can only be written like `REGEXP '[0-9](st|nd|rd|th)'`

Comment: Thanks, do you know if it is possible to use this in a replace command? while the query works, the replace changes zero rows (even after adding the function found here: https://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/

Comment: What do you need to get in the end? just the `st`, `nd`, `rd` or `th` or the numbers with those suffixes? What if the entry has no matching pattern?

Comment: I need to replace any instance of any of the ordinals with a comma followed by the year, so for example Feb 22nd should become Feb 22, 2017

Comment: I think you cannot use that function as you do not have access to backreferences.

Comment: ah ok...do you suppose there is any workaround within MySQL? (or do I need to build something in PHP that queries, loops, and updates each record)

Comment: It will be much easier with PHP as its PCRE regexes are quite powerful.

Comment: Ok, I will try that thanks for the help

Comment: MariaDB 10.0.5 (released 11/2013) uses PCRE; switch to that (or some newer version).